# Selenium webdriver vs Sahi

Tags: selenium, ui-testing, sahi

I referred some [blogs](http://blog.sahi.co.in/2010_04_01_archive.html) and earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi) on stack-overflow for this question.. But those comparisons were related with earlier version of selenium(1.0).. As current version of selenium(webdriver) is quite rich and also supports cross-browser and other functionality(even Watir-WebDriver  uses selenium).. Can any one provide some basic comparative analysis of sahi with current version of selenium webdriver.. Any suggestions would be appreciated.. Thanks..

Comment: I'm using selenium with Ruby for automation and I haven't yet come upon a limitation..The only drawback I'm aware of Selenium is that you cannot perform load/performance testing..Watir is very similar to Selenium in the synta of commands but I feel that there is less 'material' out there to help you learn..Sahi I've never heard of it until today but here is a link that compares the 3 of them. http://www.qatestingtools.com/node/368

Comment: Thanks @Neo for asking this question. I wonder what will be a good place for asking this question if not stackexchange.